# How to combine two tasks in gradle

Tags: gradle

I wanted to combine below two tasks into one task. doing the second task as  a doLast in gradle

Task1

```
task downloadFile(type: MyDownload) {
sourceUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/xxx/xx'
target = new File('E:/bookstore/', 'build.zip')
}
```

Task2

```
task copyArtifact(type: Copy) {
    from file("E:/bookstore/")
    into file("C:/mldata2/src/main/ml-modules/")

    doLast{
    def dirName ="$tempTestFilePath"
   file ( dirName ).list().each{
   f -> delete "${dirName}/${f}" 
    }
    }
}
```

I need to combine these two task as a one Gradle task

Comment: currently i am using dependOn but i need merge two tasks as a one

Answer (score 1):

Use [`finalizedBy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:finalizer_tasks):

```
downloadFile.finalizedBy copyArtifact
```

When you run `downloadFile` task, gradle will run `copyArtifact` task after it

Comment: currently i am using dependOn but i need merge two tasks as a one